# Get and Use Comment ID in Wordpress lookup array

Tags: wordpress, post

I'm trying to show custom posts that contain a meta variable that matches a comment ID. I am using the following code whereby i need to pull in the comment ID dynamically:

```
 <?php 
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'paidbriefs', 'meta_key' => 'Comment_ID', 'meta_value' => **CURRENT COMMEND ID TO GO HERE** ,   'posts_per_page' => 10 );
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
 echo 'paid';
 endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

 I have tried using 
 <?php comment_ID();?>
```

to get the comment ID but this does not work. The code works if I input the numeric comment id but I cant get it to work with by pulling the id in dynamically. Can anyone help with how to do this, it's driving me mad!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 comment_ID();
```

prints/echoes the ID directly, so

```
 'meta_value' => get_comment_ID(), ...
```

might be what you are looking for.

It's a common gotcha with the Wordpress helper functions, to confuse those which echo a variable directly with those returning values :)

Comment: Mate, this is awesome, thanks a lot, this has been confusing me for days and I've been going round in circles building all kinds of nonsense to try and get the value not echo it. Thanks again!!!!!